C++20 std::async with template lambda of zero arguments
Is it possible to call std::async with a template lambda that has 0 arguments? Thanks
*<tparams> in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda
#include <future>
#include <array>

int main() {
    auto func = []<int n>() {
      std::array<double, n> arr;    
    };

    func.operator()<5>(); // This compiles

    std::async(func.operator()<5>); // This doesn't compile

    return 0;
}


This has nothing to do with lambdas or templates or std::async per se. You simply cannot refer to a member function this way object.member_function_name in a context other than a call to that function.

Are you limited to C++20? Or just mention it because it adds the template lambdas?

Replace your faulty line with either of these depending on your intent
std::async([&func] {  func.operator()<5>(); }); //lambda remains withing its original scope
std::async([f =func] {  f.operator()<5>(); }); //lambda is copied
std::async([f =std::move(func)] {  f.operator()<5>(); }); // lambda is moved into the async's lambda inner scope

Function objects cannot bind to its first arguments by dots, it's not Python ;-)
There are, of course more methods to do that, but to me lambdas are the cleanest ones.
Another option is to use some sort of bind flavour.
To me there is no real benefit of it unless additional arguments need to be ignored (not the case here) or C++11 is used and move-only types are involved (does not seem the case either).
Still, if you prefer bind:
std::bind(&decltype(func)::operator()<5>, &func); // reference to func, mind its lifetime
std::bind(&decltype(func)::operator()<5>, func); // copy
std::bind(&decltype(func)::operator()<5>, std::move(func)); // move to inner scope of the function object created by bind

...or std::bind_front
std::bind_front(&decltype(func)::operator()<5>, &func);
std::bind_front(&decltype(func)::operator()<5>, func);
std::bind_front(&decltype(func)::operator()<5>, std::move(func));


I'd prefer std::bind_front. Plain std::bind among other things will happily accept excessive arguments and silently ignore them.

Don't use std::bind; it has quirks, and lambda (which also has quirks) can do everything std::bind can do and more.  If you use std::bind without understanding its quirks, you are walking blindfolded in a minefield, and there is no need to learn the quirks (because lambda can solve the same problems), so save your soul.

Just for completeness, if upgrading to C++23 is an option and the lambda is non-capturing, you can make it static:
#include <future>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    auto func = []<int n>() static
    {
        std::array<double, n> arr;    
    };
    func.operator()<5>(); // This compiles.
    std::async(func.operator()<5>); // This also compiles.
}

